# Plain JavaScript on-page-load event not working

Tags: javascript, events, onload, domcontentloaded

The question is pretty simple: why is nither of those are working when they should? Tried in latest chrome and FF

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  alert("window on domcontentready");
}, false);

window.onload = function() {
  alert("window on load");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FHHgA/4/

Comment: Because you chose `onLoad` in jsFiddle. Change it to `no wrap - in <head>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript is loaded on onload (inside jsfiddle), so onload won't fire, because it already fired.
Switch `onload` to `no wrap - in <head>`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank html file and paste in your js, opening the html file will show the alerts. However it doesnt seem to display the alerts in in JSFiddler.